# How to reference a value outside of the request function

Tags: javascript, request

When i run the code below it logs out "test". However when i move the console.log statement inside the request function it logs the new value of splitBody. How do I make that newly set splitBody variable to be able to be referenced outside of the function and to retain its new value.

```
var splitBody = "test"
request('http://www.example.com', function (error, response, body) {
splitBody = body.split(" ");
}
console.log(splitBody)
```

Comment: You can't do that.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: make your code synchronous. post the contents of your request function for further help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is an anti-pattern and can be resolved in numerous ways. One way would be to wrap your dependent code in a function that accepts splitBody as an argument and call it in the `request` callback

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are sending an ajax request through you're request method. The function in the second parameter of request will be called once the response of the request is received. Javascript will not wait for the response and continue to execute the next lines of code. In this case it is the console.log method.

Comment: can I add a conditional that delays the console.log method until the function is complete?

Comment: you may never know when the response from the server will arrive, hence delaying the console.log is not a reliable solution. This is why callbacks are used, they are called when the required operation has been performed. In your case an ajax request. So do you're consle.log in the function after splitBody = body.split(" ");